# How to convert multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, pivot

Current Result is like below: (more than 100 rows)

```
target    type
------    -------
A1         client
B10        agent
C20        boss
D123       client
E321       agent
A5         boss
```

How can I convert into below expected result?

```
A1       B10    C20  D123   E321   A5
------   -----  ---- ----   ---    ---
client   agent  boss client agent  boss
```

Comment: You want operation usually called pivoting. Its syntax differs across db vendors or it must be workarounded by plain SQL if it is not supported by some db vendor at all. It's crucial for you to specify your db vendor to obtain more precise advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN target = 'A' THEN type END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN target = 'B' THEN type END) AS B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN target = 'C' THEN type END) AS C
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: may be the example is too simplified, actually the target is the userName with different combination, like ABC123, CBD321, BDA421 and get more than 100 rows

Comment: Then you didn't ask the right question.  Please include the real query in your question in this case.

Comment: sorry just edited with more detailed information.

Comment: My answer doesn't really change...just add more `CASE` expressions to cover each of the 100 columns you expect in the output.  Your particular database might have a tool which makes this easier, e.g. crosstab in Postgres.